# backbone and $el element

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm trying to develop my first backbone application. All seems ok, but when i render the view and append some html to the `$el`, nothing is rendered in the page.
Rest service calls done ok, the `Backbone.Router.extend` is declared inside `$(document).ready(function () {});` to ensure that the DOM is created.
Debugging my javascript, the `el` element get to contain the correct value in the *innerHTML* property, but when the whole page is rendered, this value doesn't appear in the page.

¿What am i doing wrong?

My View code:

```
window.ProductsListView = Backbone.View.extend({

  id: 'tblProducts',
  tagName: 'div',

  initialize: function (options) {
    this.model.on('reset', this.render, this);
  },

  render: function () {
    // save a reference to the view object
    var self = this;

    // instantiate and render children
    this.model.each(function (item) {
      var itemView = new ProductListItemView({ model: item });
      var elValue = itemView.render().el;
      self.$el.append(elValue);  // Here: the $el innerHTML is ok, but in the page it disappear. The id of element is div#tblProducts, so the element seems correct
    });

    return this;
  }
});

window.ProductListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

  tagName: 'div',

  template: _.template(
      '<%= title %>'
    ),

  initialize: function (options) {

    this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    this.model.on('reset', this.render, this);
    this.model.on('destroy', this.close, this);
  },

  render: function () {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    // $(this.el).html('aaaaaa');  // This neither works: it's not a template problem

    return this;
  },

  close: function () {
    $(this.el).unbind();
    $(this.el).remove();
  }
});
```

Here i load products (inside `Backbone.Router.extend`). This is executed correctly:

```
this.productsList = new ProductsCollection();
this.productsListView = new ProductsListView({ model: this.productsList });
this.productsList.fetch();
```

And this is the html element i want to render:

```
<div id="tblProducts">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with simplified issue? It would greatly help to help you..

Comment: I haven't got reset services uploaded, so my code only works in my dev machine. Next time i will prepare all better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you have posted, you are not actually inserting your `ProductsListView` in to the DOM or attaching it to an existing DOM element.

The way I like to look at it is you have two types of Views:

- Those that are dynamically generated based on data returned from the server
- Those that already exist on the page

Usually in the case of lists, the list already exists on the page and it's items are dynamically added. I have taken your code and restructured it slightly in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zJAnu/). You will see that the `ProductListView` is binding to an existing `ul`, and `ProductItemView`'s are dynamically appended when they are added to the Collection.

[Updated jsfiddle to demonstrate Collection.reset](http://jsfiddle.net/h9242/)

Comment: but what if i want to fetch data in collection from rest service?, instead of adding elements one by one. I thought i had to subscribe to "reset" event and in render make a collection.each. I'm trying to simulate using productCollection.reset(...) with no luck. jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/raultruco/zJAnu/3/)

Comment: You were very close! I have forked and modified your fiddle to show the differences [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AJjmd/). Note that the reset event captured by `ProductListView` is from `ProductCollection`, not `Product`.

Comment: it doesn't work for me... neither see the difference (only collection naming instead of model). Thank @juco

Comment: Please see the bottom link on my original answer. This is working hopefully as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The `el` property exists within the view if it is rendered or not. You can't say it is ok there because Backbone will create an element if no element is passed (empty div).

If you want to render the view you should determine what is the container of the element? Do you have an html you want to attach the view to?

Try passing a container element by calling the view with an `el` like

```
this.productsListView = new ProductsListView({ model: this.productsList, el : $("#container") });
```

Of course you can create the view and attach it to the DOM later:

```
el: $("#someElementID") //grab an existing element
el.append(view.render().el);
```

Your view wont exist in the dom until you attach it somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, i understand. Talking about the time of adding the element to DOM. Which do you prefer 1) pass el to the view and render itself or 2) add later using $("#someContainerID").append(view.render().el) ?